# Mobile device detector: iOS or Android code

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, cell

Using available code on iOS or Android devices, is it possible to directly detect and count other nearby mobile devices by their radio signals?  Are their functions in the toolboxes that are made available that can give this type of low-level information?
Need to count how many nearby devices there are, not connect with them (though ID'ing them would be great too to avoid double counting).
The other devices will other phones/tablets running iOS or Android, and they will not/cannot be required to have any software or app specifically relating to this function installed -- the idea is to detect nearby unknown iOS/Android devices.
For example, this could be accomplished be detecting the WiFi signal of a device that is transmitting WiFi.
Order of preference for what signals to use in order to make the detection is based on the likelihood of their being on:
cell/3G > WiFi > Bluetooth > NFC.

Thanks

Comment: nota: for NFC you'd need to be a lot closer than just `nearby`

Comment: cell signal is used to communicate between a device and a cell. There is no integrated system in the device to detect other signals. wifi and BT would need to be active on the detected device.